# How to use efi partition for windows and multiple linux multi boot setup

Tags: ubuntu, multi-boot, windows-11, arch-linux, efi

I recently bought a laptop and wanted to install multiple Linux flavors alongside the provided Windows 11.

In a [video tutorial](https://youtu.be/Crleyglb4mo), they suggest creating a separate EFI partition and selecting it as the EFI partition for later Linux installations, with the option to update so that all boot information is kept.

However, my laptop already had an EFI partition labeled something like "Windows boot partition," and I didn't want to risk interfering with Windows. So, during the installation of the first Linux distro (Ubuntu), I created a new 500MB EFI partition and set it to be used for EFI. The installation finished smoothly, and both Windows and Ubuntu were available in the grub menu.

Now, when I inspect the partitions, it seems that Ubuntu has updated the existing EFI partition (`/dev/nvme0np1`) instead of using the one I created (which is `/dev/nvme0np10` and not mounted). My first question is if my assumption is correct? Secondly, I'm planning to install Arch Linux. Should I point the installation to the existing EFI partition, or should I not worry about it and let Arch figure it out?

[image]